# Serialized version contained a blank language value!

Tags: sxa, sxa-cli

I am trying to serialize some Sitecore items from the Sitecore instance running in my docker container. So I try this:

```
dotnet sitecore ser pull
```

This works most of the time. But occasionally I get an error like:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Serialized version contained a blank language value!
```

I am not sure how or why this would be the case. The only way I have found to fix this issue is to delete the item in Sitecore, and then re-create it.
Anyone seen this error?

Comment: I got the same problem and ended up cleaning the db and re-creating. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me after modifying the default App Route in a JSS app and deploying it to Sitecore. Trying to serialize the new components and content resulted in this error. I noticed that the App Routes had not only the default "English" language variant, but also an "Invariant" version.

A post from Maarten Willebrands describes the problem and a fix if you are not using Sitecore's Publishing Service.
[Sitecore SXA/JSS – Invariant language versions and access denied exceptions](https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/07/06/sitecore-sxa-invariant-language-versions-and-access-denied-exceptions/)

Disabling the FlagPublishingGroupingItems as recommended and rebuilding the database allowed me to again deploy the JSS app with the modified App Route, and successfully serialize the content.

Comment: See also https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29179/how-to-delete-invariant-language