# How to delete Invariant Language

Tags: multilingual, content-management, language-fallback

Using Sitecore 10.1 with commerce.

I see this Invariant language for some of the items. Here is a snap of a template's standard values (Regular custom Sitecore template) and all the items created from this template have it.

[image]
Performed the following steps with no luck:

1. Delete items with no language

```
DELETE FROM [VersionedFields] WHERE [Language] IN ('','hy-AM')  
DELETE FROM [UnversionedFields] WHERE [Language] IN ('','hy-AM')
```

2. Run the Sync Content Path command as this is a commerce instance.

[image]

3. Deleted all languages under system node except english.
4. Indexed master & web databases

Comment: Is this happening on commerce specific templates?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal This is for regular Sitecore templates

Comment: @Qwerty if you run the following queries on the master database: `SELECT * FROM [VersionedFields] WHERE [Language] = ''` and `SELECT * FROM [UnversionedFields] WHERE [Language] = ''`, what is the count?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya There are no records for either queries

Comment: The template which is having the Invariant Language issue, have you created it on the Sitecore instance or has it been installed? If it is installed, check on the environment where the package was created to see if there also it is as Invariant language

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I created that template in local instance. It is not an installed one.

Comment: So the issue is on your local instance? Can you make sure to register languages if you have custom ones

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Do not have any languages now except for english

Comment: If you re-create the template, does the issue persist? It may be that due to an error previously when you created the template

Answer (score 8):

You could do this with Unicorn (it will not fail, even with these rogue invariant item versions) but you can also achieve it with the built-in developer tools.

Before you do, set [your default system serialization format to YAML](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-serialization.html). By default you can set this in `App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Serialization.config`.

Go to your Developer ribbon, Serialize the item in question.

[image: Serialize Item]

Now go to your `App_Data/serialization` folder and find the file in question.

In the YAML file you will find something like this:

```
- Language: 
  Versions:
  - Version: 1
    Fields:
    - ID: "25bed78c-4957-4165-998a-ca1b52f67497"
      Hint: __Created
      Value: 20210630T100059Z
    - ID: "5dd74568-4d4b-44c1-b513-0af5f4cda34f"
      Hint: __Created by
      Value: |
        sitecore\Admin
- Language: en
  Versions:
  - Version: 1
    Fields:
    - ID: "25bed78c-4957-4165-998a-ca1b52f67497"
      Hint: __Created
      Value: 20210708T093402Z
    - ID: "5dd74568-4d4b-44c1-b513-0af5f4cda34f"
      Hint: __Created by
      Value: |
        sitecore\Anonymous
```

Notice the first one has no language specification, it reads `Language:` .

Delete this rogue version and save the file.

Now go back to your ribbon, and select "Revert Item".

This should clear it up for you.

[image: Revert Item]

Also note that you are likely to run into this problem again, as this is a known bug in SXA. You can find some details in this blog post: [Sitecore SXA/JSS – Invariant language versions and access denied exceptions](https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/07/06/sitecore-sxa-invariant-language-versions-and-access-denied-exceptions/)

#### Update, the SQL way

I also strongly believe you did not try out the comment from Hishaam above. When you have "Invariant Language" showing up in your Content Editor, there most definitely *will* be entries in your `VersionedFields` table that shows  it. You could get rid of them by executing a SQL statement on both your `Master` and `Web` databases.

[image: SQL Management Studio]

- `DELETE FROM [Sitecore.Master].[dbo].[VersionedFields] WHERE [Language] = ''`
- `DELETE FROM [Sitecore.Web].[dbo].[VersionedFields] WHERE [Language] = ''`

Don't forget to completely reset IIS after making changes on SQL level.